# Evaluate $ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^3+x+1}dx$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals

I want to evaluate the following integral
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^3+x+1}\>dx$$
via Residue theorem. Or, any other methods are welcome!

Actually i just compute this via mathematica, but it seems
the command

Integrate[1/(x^3 + x + 1), {x, 0, Infinity}]

gives some terrible output not a compact or simple form.

My first trial is factor $x^3+x+1$ into linear terms but it does not seem easy,
I have difficulties for finding poles, $i.e$, finding zeros for $x^3+x+1=0$. And having trouble for finding proper contour.

Comment: The problem with using the Residue theorem for this is that is applies to closed contours only, but the positive real line is not closed. To apply the residue theorem, you need to close the contour in such a way that you can determine the integrals along the other elements (often just by showing one or more of the elements goes to 0 when the upper limit here goes to $\infty$). The reason mathematica doesn't give you a closed form answer is that this polynomial has ugly roots. The closed form is really nasty. See wikipedia for "cubic function" for how to find them.

Comment: Have you tried the contour where you have a line segment from zero to infinity, and then a semi-circle from infinity back to 0? I have a feeling you can do that because of the maximum modulus principle. Then, you have a closed contour and may apply the residue theorem, or Cauchy's Integral formula.

Comment: because the poles of the integrand are ugly, the result will be ugly no matter what technique you use. If you really want residue theorem: integrate $\log(z)/(z^3+z+1)$ around a keyhole contour in teh complex plane

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that $x^3+x+1$ has only one real root below per the Cardano’s formula

$$r= \sqrt[3]{\frac{\sqrt{93}-9}{18}}-\sqrt[3]{\frac{\sqrt{93}+9}{18}}=  -0.6823
$$

Then, decompose the integrand accordingly to integrate as follows

\begin{align}
&\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^3+x+1}dx\\
=&\ \int_0^\infty \frac1{(x-r)(x^2+rx-1/r)}dx\\
=&\ \int_0^\infty \frac r{2r +3}\left(-\frac1{x-r}+\frac{x+2r}{x^2+rx-1/r}\right)dx\\
=&\ \frac r{2r +3}\bigg(-\ln\frac{x-r}{\sqrt{ x^2+rx-1/r}}
+\frac{ 3r \tan^{-1}\frac{2x+r}{\sqrt{1-3/r} } }{\sqrt{1-3/r}}\bigg)_{0}^{\infty}\\
=&\ \frac {3r}{2r +3}\bigg(\ln(-r)^{\frac12}
-\frac{(-r)^{\frac32}}{\sqrt{3-r} } \bigg(\frac\pi2 + \tan^{-1}\frac{(-r)^{\frac32}}{\sqrt{3-r} }\bigg)\bigg) \\ 
\end{align}

Comment: Great answer. The idea is awesome.